# flask-restplus nested namespace with blueprint and namespace

Tags: flask, flask-restplus

I made api server with `flask-restplus`.

While working with it, I noticed that it maybe have to versioning for scaling up.

So refer the docs, I found Namespace and Blueprint is usuable.

First, file structure like this.

```
/app
  - /main
    - __init__.py
    - /controller
      - /v1/
        - article_controller.py
  - __init__.py
```

[/main/v1/__init__.py]

```
from flask_restplus import Namespace, Api
from flask import Blueprint

from .article_controller import api as article_ns


blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)

api = Api(blueprint,
          title='Appeal API',
          version='1.0',
          description='Appeal API',
          )

api.add_namespace(article_ns, path='/articles')
```

I import `article_controller.py` and add it via `add_namespace()`.

[/main/__init__.py]

```
from flask_restplus import Api
from flask import Blueprint

from app.main.controller.v1 import api as api_v1


blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)

api = Api(blueprint,
          title='Appeal API v1',
          version='1.0',
          description='Appeal API v1',
          #   prefix='/api'
          )

# Version1
api.add_namespace(api_v1, path='/v1/')
```

Import `v1` and add it to namespace.

But when I access to `/v1/articles`, Not found errors has occured.

I can't catch where is the wrong code.

Any solution here?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Where did you create your flask app?

in your app (the root of your project), you should have something like

> app.py

that's where you define your flask app and register blueprints in it

like...

```
from flask import Flask
from main import blueprint as api1

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api1)
app.run(debug=True)
```

[look at this example in docs](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scaling.html#use-with-blueprints)